# How to check the length of input char array (%s) using scanf() in C

Tags: c, input, scanf

I need to check the length of an input using the function `scanf()`.
I'm using an array of char (%s) to store the input, but I wasn't able to check the length of this input.

this below is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char chr[] = "";
int n;

void main()
{
    printf("\n");
    printf("Enter a character: ");
    scanf("%s",chr);     
    printf("You entered %s.", chr);
    printf("\n");

    n = sizeof(chr);    
    printf("length n = %d \n", n);
    printf("\n");

}
```

it's giving me back that "length n = 1" for the output in each case I've tried.

**How can I check the length of the input in this case?**
Thank You.

Comment: [`strlen`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strlen.3.html), but you have UB because `char chr[] = "";` only reserves 1 byte. Try something like `char chr[256] = "";` instead.

Comment: scanf() returns an `int` telling you how many chars have been converted. Be aware that you are storing this input into a non-allocated memory (as "" is only 1 bytes length)

Comment: @Jack Re: "_returns an `int` telling you how many chars have been converted_" - Not quite. It will return `1` if it read a string, no matter how many chars it used up.

Comment: [example of `scanf` for string, what it returns, and `strlen`](https://godbolt.org/z/GfYo1585v)

Comment: @yano Or [safer](https://godbolt.org/z/M6aMYrvr5)

Comment: @TedLyngmo shouldn't the 255 limit be for `scanf`?

Comment: @yano Yeah, I updated it. I blame my tired eyes :-)

Comment: @yano I changed chr[256] and I've included <string.h>. And now it's working, thank you

Comment: @TedLyngmo thanks for correction - I blame my tired memory :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> to check the length of input char array (%s) using scanf()

- Do not use the raw `"%s"`, use a *width* limit: 1 less than buffer size.
- Use an adequate sized buffer.  `char chr[] = "";` is only 1 `char`.
- Use `strlen()` to determine string length when the input does not read *null characters*.

  ```
    char chr[100];
    if (scanf("%99s", chr) == 1) {
      printf("Length: %zu\n", strlen(chr));
    }
  ```
- Pedantic: Use `"%n"` to store the offset of the scan if code might read *null characters* (this is rarely or nefariously encountered).

  ```
    char chr[100];
    int n1, n2;
    if (scanf(" %n%99s%n", &n1, chr, &n2) == 1) {
      printf("Length: %d\n", n2 - n1);
    }
  ```

Comment: That `%n` has flown under my radar. That's so nice and actually answers the question how to get the length directly from `scanf`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Note important to account for potential leading whitespace to get the right length as `"%n"` counts from the beginning of the scan, yet `"%s"` does not save leading  (or any) white-space.

Comment: Got it! Niftly little option I must say! `" %n%99[^\n]%n"` could be an option to get the whitespaces right from the start (and include them in the string, if that's wanted).

Comment: @TedLyngmo To include white-space (except a `'\n'`), could use `"%99[^\n]%n"`.  Beware of special handling  needed in all these formats when `chr[]` is only `"\n"`.

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof`  is a compile time unary operator which can be used to compute the size of its operand.if you want to calculate the length of the string the you have to use `strlen()`.like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
  
int main()
{
    char Str[1000];
  
    printf("Enter the String: ");
    if(scanf("%999s", Str) == 1) // limit the number of chars to  sizeof Str - 1
    {                            // and == 1 to check that scanning 1 item worked
        printf("Length of Str is %zu", strlen(Str));
    }
  
    return 0;
}
```